# How do I select parent of parent of link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, playlist

I'm creating a page which I want to have multiple playlists for an  player.

This is the script, you probably have seen it before:

```
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;
init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('.player');
    playlist = $('.album_tracks_container');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
        $('.audioplayer').removeClass('audioplayer-stopped');
        $('.audioplayer').addClass('audioplayer-playing');
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];   
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
        $('.audioplayer').removeClass('audioplayer-stopped');
        $('.audioplayer').addClass('audioplayer-playing');
    });
}
function run(link, player){
    $('.album_tracks_container').find('.album_tracks_light, .album_tracks_dark').removeClass('album_tracks_active');
    player.src = link.attr('href');
    par = link.parent();
    par.addClass('album_tracks_active').siblings().removeClass('album_tracks_active');
    $('.album_tracks_container').find('.album_tracks_light, .album_tracks_dark').find('.album_tracks_number, .album_tracks_text').removeClass('album_tracks_number-text_active');
    par.find('.album_tracks_number, .album_tracks_text').addClass('album_tracks_number-text_active');
    audio[0].load();
    audio[0].play();
}
```

Now I want to change that playlist var to something like this (yeah I don't know javaScript but I hope you get what I want to do)

```
$('a').click(function(){
    playlist = $(this).closest('.album_tracks_container');
});
```

to append it to the closest div with that class to the link i click.

The reason I need to do this is because I have multiple '.album_tracks_container' in the page, and without a code change it will only select the top one as a playlist (when i play a song in the ones below, next song will continue at the top playlist)

So yeah, I want that playlist var to be = the closest .album_tracks_container to the 'a' (link) I click.

I hope I make sense.

this is the html

```
<body>
    <div class="player_container">
        <audio class="player" preload="auto" controls>
            <source src="media/playlist1/01.wav"/>
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="content_container">
        <div id="A">
            <div class="album_container">
                <div class="album_art playlist1"></div>
                <div class="album_artist_title">
                    <span class="album_artist_title_text">playlist1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="album_album_title">
                    <span class="album_album_title_text">3 songs</span>
                </div>
                <ul class="album_tracks_container">
                    <li class="album_tracks_light">
                        <span class="album_tracks_number">01</span> <span class="album_tracks_text">song 1</span>
                        <a href="media/playlist1/01.wav"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="album_tracks_dark">
                        <span class="album_tracks_number">02</span> <span class="album_tracks_text">song 2</span>
                        <a href="media/playlist1/02.wav"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="album_tracks_light">
                        <span class="album_tracks_number">03</span> <span class="album_tracks_text">song 3</span>
                        <a href="media/playlist1/03.wav"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="C">
            <div class="album_container">
                <div class="album_art playlist2"></div>
                <div class="album_artist_title">
                    <span class="album_artist_title_text">playlist2</span>
                </div>
                <div class="album_album_title">
                    <span class="album_album_title_text">3 songs</span>
                </div>
                <ul class="album_tracks_container">
                    <li class="album_tracks_light">
                        <span class="album_tracks_number">01</span> <span class="album_tracks_text">song 1</span>
                        <a href="media/playlist2/01.wav"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="album_tracks_dark">
                        <span class="album_tracks_number">02</span> <span class="album_tracks_text">song 2</span>
                        <a href="media/playlist2/02.wav"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="album_tracks_light">
                        <span class="album_tracks_number">03</span> <span class="album_tracks_text">song 3</span>
                        <a href="media/playlist2/03.wav"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code will find the nearest parent with that class. Ok what's your problem.? Can you please explain about your situation more.?

Comment: basically what happens is, because the tracks = playlist.find('li a'); it will mixup it with other playlist since they share same numbering

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't know javascript"?

Comment: i mean i'm not good at it, im a beginner and i try to learn by experimenting   when i use this $('a').click(function(){
    playlist = $(this).closest('.album_tracks_container');
}); it seems to break the playlist and when i click a song im directed to source of soundfile instead

Comment: Say I listen to track 2 on playlist 2, when done playing it will jump to track 3 on playlist 1 - thats my problem.

Comment: That's because of the `href` you had given. You don't want the anchors default behaviour, you can use `e.preventDefault()`. But inside the event handler you must specify what to do next.

Comment: Ok, `playlist.find('a')[0]` refers to the very first `a` element, regardless the playlist.

Comment: So, if I'm right, this has nothing to do with a click.

Comment: Well it does have to do with a click because - When you click one ofthe li a, it will start a song, and what i want to happen is for it to select the parent that holds those links as the playlist, instead of selecting it like i do in the OP, because it mixup both playlists into each other.

Comment: Thats what I tried to do with my example but it did not work and I don't know how I can make it work.

Comment: I understand, you need to store a reference to the playlist on click on one of its links.

Comment: In fact, that's what you already do with `current`. Maybe you could use this index to retrieve the element like so : `playlist.eq(current)`?

Comment: Sorry, `current` is for the `li` right? I'm not well awaken... Give me a minute.

Comment: Yes it is, current is to determine which track is playing and which one comes next in the playlist

Comment: In the answer I've posted, `currentPlaylist` is a jQuery object, not an index, so you can use it directly (NO need for `playlist.eq(currentPlaylist)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to do with this `$('a').click()` since there is already a click event registered. Anyway, let me try a guess. What do you think about the following code?

```
var currentPlaylist;
playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    link = $(this);
    current = link.parent().index();
    currentPlaylist = link.closest('.album_tracks_container'); // <<<
    run(link, audio[0]);
    $('.audioplayer').removeClass('audioplayer-stopped');
    $('.audioplayer').addClass('audioplayer-playing');
});
```

Comment: Oh my, it works fantastic! You are wonderful thank you very much!

Comment: Ah I tried to vote up and it didn't work and didn't notice that checkbox - There we go! :)

Comment: @Hrodebert You need at least 15 reputation to vote up : http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges. This answer is not so interesting to deserve an upvote anyway :)

Comment: @Hrodebert A little remark. Don't frighten people by saying you have no skills, you're not so bad actually :) Instead, try to make things clear by simplifying your code as much as you can and making clean sentences, otherwise you'll see the comments section growing over and over, which is also discouraging for the readers. Have fun :)